# fft artificial defects due to finite sampling frequency

Tags: matlab, fft

I use Matlab to calculate the `fft` result of a time series data. The signal has an unknown fundamental frequency (~80 MHz in this case), together with several high order harmonics (1-20th order). However, due to finite sampling frequency (500 MHz in this case), I always get the mixing frequencies from high order frequency (7-20), e.g. 7th with a peak at `abs(2*500-80*7)=440 MHz`, 8th with frequency 360 MHz and 13th with a peak at `abs(13*80-2*500)=40 MHz`.  Does anyone know how to get rid of these artificial mixing frequencies? One possible way is to increase the sampling frequency to sufficient large value. However, my data set has fixed number of data and time range. So the sampling frequency is actually determined by the property of the data set. Any solutions to this problem?

(I have image for this problem but I don't have enough reputation to post a image. Sorry for bring inconvenience for understanding this question)

Comment: do you mind uploading your image to www.imgur.com?

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting on a fundamental property of sampling - when you sample data at a fixed frequency `fs`, you cannot tell the difference between two signals with the same amplitude but different frequencies, where one has `f1=fs/2 - d` and the other has `f2=f2/2 + d`. This effect is frequently used to advantage - for example in mixers - but at other times, it's an inconvenience.

Unless you are looking for this mixing effect (done, for example, at the digital receiver in a modern MRI scanner), you need to apply a "brick wall filter" with a cutoff frequency of `fs/2`. It is not uncommon to have filters with a roll-off of 24 dB / octave or higher - in other words, they let "everything through" below the cutoff, and "stop everything" above it.

Data acquisition vendors will often supply filtering solutions with their ADC boards for exactly this reason.

Long way to say: "That's how digitization works". But it's true - that is how digitization works.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, one low-pass filters the signal to below half the sample rate before sampling.  Otherwise, after sampling, there is usually no way to separate any aliased high frequency noise (your high order harmonics) from the more useful spectrum below (Nyquist) half the sample rate.

If you don't filter the signal before sampling it, the defect is inherent in the sample vector, not the FFT.